# Quiz game in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Need some assistance in designing a quiz game.  I have the following in Python  - one string and one list.

```
quiz_string = '''there are two types of loops in programming.  The blank1 loop and the blank2 loop'''

answer_list = ['for', 'while']
```

A user will be prompted as follows:  What should go in blank1?

If the user answers 'for', then the 'blank1' in quiz_string variable will be replaced by 'for' from the answer_list variable.  This process should repeat for blank2.

Any help on the code that should be used would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying you want to replace `blank1` with 'for' and `blank2` with 'while'?

Comment: And what if the user enters `while` then `for`? That is also correct...

Answer (score 2):

You can use a formatting string with the appropriate variables:

```
quiz_string = '''there are two types of loops in programming.  The {} loop and the {} loop'''
guesses = ['blank1', 'blank2']
print(quiz_string.format(*guesses))
```

When the user inputs the correct answers, you would then replace the elements in `guesses` with the user's inputs and make the same `print` call again. It will then replace the `{}` with the new values in `guesses`.

Answer (score 1):

`string.replace()` might help.

For example :

```
quiz_string = '''there are two types of loops in programming.  The blank1 loop and the blank2 loop'''
answer_list = ['for', 'while']

blank1 = input('First Blank ')
blank2 = input('Second Blank ')

if blank1 in answer_list :
    quiz_string = quiz_string.replace('blank1', blank1)
if blank2 in answer_list :
    quiz_string = quiz_string.replace('blank2', blank2)

print(quiz_string)
```

You can modify the validations as necessary.